# jQuery use sort after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am just newbie to the jQuery UI. I have two divs. One in the left side and another one in the right side. I want that when I will drag one element from left div to right div it should sort both left and right divs. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this?
 Here is my code for so far

```
<div name="list-a" class="droppable">
  <h3>List A</h3>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
      <div class="draggable" id="1" name="1">
          <a href="#">Element 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="2" name="3">
          <a href="#">Element 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="3" name="3">
          <a href="#">Element 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div name="list-b" class="droppable">
  <h3>List B</h3>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
      <div class="draggable" id="5" name="5">
          <a href="#">Element 5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="6" name="6">
          <a href="#">Element 6</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".draggable").draggable();
  jQuery(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var id, state;
      state = $(this).attr("name");
      id = $(this).closest(".droppable").attr("id");
      alert("Belongs to list: " + state);
    }
 });

});
</script>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/B2DFG/).

Here you can see it is doing both drag and drop but its not doing sorting after drag and drop.
Any suggestion or help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to start from [`connected-list`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) sortable demo of jQuery UI, and make some change accordingly.

In this way your lists are sortable and you can drag-drop elements betwenn the lists, you'll get the sorting feature.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".droppable>div").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable>div"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RmLAA/

### UPDATE

For the empty lists just set a `min-height` of your container div class and it works fine, a completely empty div have no height so the droppable will not be fired.

Code:

```
.task-wrapper{
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RmLAA/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply. But you can see in your fiddle when all the elements are made drop to List B from List A(when List A is made blank), and when you will again drag any elemts from List B to List A its not working.